# list of dictionaries comprehension - multiple conditions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, multiple-conditions

I have a problem with multiple conditions with list:

```
listionary = [{u'city': u'paris', u'id': u'1', u'name': u'paul'},
              {u'city': u'madrid', u'id': u'2', u'name': u'paul'},
              {u'city': u'berlin', u'id': u'3', u'name': u'tom'},
              {u'city': u'madrid', u'id': u'4', u'name': u'tom'}]
```

I try to delete items that meet both conditions simultaneously.

```
[elem for elem in listionary if (elem.get('name')!='paul' and elem.get('city')!='madrid')]
```

In this case element is removed if meet at least one condition, I try to do it in several ways, any ideas?

Expected output:

```
[{u'city': u'paris', u'id': u'1', u'name': u'paul'}
{u'city': u'berlin', u'id': u'3', u'name': u'tom'}
{u'city': u'madrid', u'id': u'4', u'name': u'tom'}]
```

I would like to remove element which meet both conditions.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the `and` to `or`.

```
[elem for elem in listionary if (elem.get('name')!='paul' or elem.get('city')!='madrid')]
```

Remember [de morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Informally: when you negate a boolean expression, you have to switch `and` with `or` in addition to switching "==" with "!=".

Comment: great, this is exactly what I was looking for. basic logical mistake, good to know. thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Your condition should have been like this

```
[e for e in data if not (e.get('name') == 'paul' and e.get('city') == 'madrid')]
```

**Output**

```
[{u'city': u'paris', u'id': u'1', u'name': u'paul'},
 {u'city': u'berlin', u'id': u'3', u'name': u'tom'},
 {u'city': u'madrid', u'id': u'4', u'name': u'tom'}]
```

This checks if the current element's `name` is `paul` and `city` is `madrid`. If both the conditions are satisfied, the `not` outside will flip it, so you will get `False` and the item will be omitted.

Basically you are checking if the current item is the one which you don't want and make the `if` condition fail if it is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**`itemgetter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get all the values into a `tuple` and then compare that:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> name_and_city = itemgetter('name', 'city')
>>> [e for e in listionary if name_and_city(e) != ('paul', 'madrid')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in fact quite static. In this case you can use `namedtuple` for performance on large data.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Profile = namedtuple('Profile', ['city', 'id', 'name'])
listionary = [Profile(*d) for d in listionary]
```

To improve readability, you can refactor the condition as a lambda expression (this assumes you are using `namedtuple`):

```
removed = lambda ele: \
   ele.name == 'paul' or \
   ele.city == 'madrid'
output = [ele for ele in listionary if not removed(ele)]
```

I think this is easier to maintain and more readable, but it may depends on who is looking at it.